# Database creation issue after running ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database

I have a propblem related to the first run of an ASP.NET MVC application containing a database.

I was forced to install a new Windows and migrate my ASP.NET MVC project to it (previously I put it on the Github respository).

In the new installation of the system - I launched VisualStudio, logged into Github and downloaded the project from the repository. However, when I try to run, I get the error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Directory lookup for the file .... / AppName.mdf "failed with the operating system error 2.
> CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors. '

The application previously used a local database. This is what connection string looks like:

```
<add name="AppNameContext" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=AppName;Integrated Security=SSPI; AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\AppName.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Did I skip any step in configuring new visual studio and don't want to create a new database?

Comment: Do you have App_Data folder?

Comment: Are you setting DataDirectory in code ?

Comment: @viveknuna - yes i have, but is empty. "|Data directory|" is only in connectionStrting

Comment: Do you have the mdf file there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application is missing the **App_Data** folder. Right click on your project, select Add, then Add **ASP.Net Folder** and choose the **App_Data** folder.